# Running! from VCVCVC

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have been trying for the last 18 months taking all my code out of the ViewController to make it more like MVC should. ( Hence the title )

I've made a small step on my own by being able to do the following within one Class object, but now I want to break it down further

A very generic example: one file contains the data

```
struct Data {
var x = 0
var y = 0
}
```

and one file for the operation

```
class Adder {

var myObject = MyClass()

var z = 1

   func addThem() {
    z = myObject.x + myObject.y
    }  
}
```

now for the salient parts of the ViewController:

```
var data = Data()
var adder = Adder()

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

// user input via textfield
data.x = Int(numeralOne.text!)!
data.y = Int(numeralTwo.text!)!

adder.addThem()  // *
answerLabel.text = String(adder.z)
}
```

Ultimately I'd like to omit the line commented with the asterisk. I thought OO's encapsulation of (data) away from (adder) allows for adder.z to just automatically update in the background without involving the ViewController. That way a subtractor class (say) can operate on the same two struct properties.

My question? How can correctly referencing them from the VC.

PS. if i include return statements in the function it makes no difference.

Comment: That's just a computed property.  Look it up in the Apple swift book.

Comment: Agreed. You could just use a computed property for `z` in your `Data` struct

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your code exactly what the relationship is between the `Data` struct and `MyClass` but if a `MyClass` object has the values of x & y that you need then the following will work

```
class MyClass {
  var x = 1
  var y = 2
}

class Adder {

  var myObject = MyClass()
  var z: Int {
    return myObject.x + myObject.y
  }

}

let adder = Adder()
print(adder.z)
```